# How to calculate annualised tracking error?

Tags: portfolio-management, returns, tracking-error

I have 36 months of relative returns and I need to calculate the annualised tracking error.

So, using 36 months of returns is it simply like below:

```
stdev(36 months of returns) * sqrt(12)
```

Why the `sqrt(12)`?

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{12}$ annualizes monthly deviations.

But I don't understand why you measure tracking error with stdev. It should be $$ ATE = \sqrt{\frac{12}{36}\sum_{i=1}^{36}(r_{b,i}-r_{t,i})^2}$$ where $r_{b,i}$ is benchmark  return for month $i$ and $r_{t,i}$ is tracking portfolio return for same period. So you shouldn't substract average error inside square.

Comment: This is correct, in particular, for ETFs. The scaling is needed for annualization. The same treatment is also employed for historical volatility estimation based on daily asset prices.

Comment: I think his "returns" are as indicated in the question "relative" returns so they correspond to $\bar{r}_i = r_{t,i} - r_{b,i}$, then he uses the approach from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_error) $TE=\sqrt{\text{Var}(\bar{r}_i)}$ is that wrong?

Comment: I have also encountered tracking error formulas without the negative average excess return term. Which is it?

Comment: SRKX, it's Ok but correct to get annualised value.